Merkle-Damgård construction without MD compliant padding
Is there an easy example of a Merkle-Damgård constructed hash that does not have Merkle-Damgård compliant padding and is collision resistant?
Is there an example that does not have MD-compliant padding and is not collision resistant?

You need to clarify your question a bit; how do you define the "MD construction"?
